# Return random name from a list of names in google sheet using script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google script. I need help with the following situation:

*I have a google sheet. In the 'IDs' Sheet, I have few names listed from A2 to A30. I want to write a macro (function) that will give a random name from the list whenever I ran the function as a msgBox notification.*

Note: I am aware of the inbuilt formula RANDBETWEN this is not helpful because everytime user changes something in the file then the formula is being updated.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please share your raw data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
function grn() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('IDs');
  const names=sh.getRange(2,1,29).getValues().flat();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(names[Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)]),'Selected Name');
}
```